# Smarty - variable addition

Tags: php, smarty

I want to add a constant value to a variable in smarty. just like:

```
{assign var='c' value='0'}
$c=$c+1
```

Comment: Is "smart t" the same as [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
{assign var='c' value=0}
{assign var='c' value=$c+1}
```

The short form should work too, but you say it doesn't.

```
{$c=0}
{$c=$c+1}
```

But this doesn't work because you're using Smarty 2, right? Because in Smarty 3 it should work.

Comment: The second way is much better.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
{assign var="c" value="`$something+$constant`"}
```

But usually the sense of template frameworks is to follow the mvc pattern. So all the logic is done in a controller. Or in the case of you some sort of php script. The view should not hold much logic(less logic better view code). So any sort of calculations should not be in a view. In mvc you will have however some sort of logic like iterations or link generation(through e.g. smarty plugins).

Answer (score 3):

You can use expressions with the [`{assign}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.builtin.functions.tpl) template function.

```
{assign var=c value=$c+1}
```

Or in its short form,

```
{$c=$c+1}
```

Comment: `syntax error: unrecognized tag: $c=$c+1 (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 439)` I'm getting this error